# How to check efficiently if collection is empty?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

… and I stress the word efficiently:

1. Fetching whole collection and calling `numChildren()` is 
   definitely out.
2. Fetching any item and using `exists()` is also out, since I don't know keys - they are autogenerated by Firebase when `push()`ing.

This is a subproblem of a well-known 'How to do determine length of a collection efficiently'.

So perhaps there will be yet another, cleaner solution.

My take is:

```
collectionRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1)
  .once('child_added').then(snap => {
    alert('Not empty');
  });
```

The problem is detecting when it's empty.

The promise returned by `once()` is suspended in pending state instead of failing instantly if there are no children.

This approach could be saved by calling `off()` after some timeout, but 2 issues arise:

1. How to determine the right amount of timeout ?
2. This workaround with timeout is incredibly lame

Answer (score 2):

You could try this approach, however I'm not entirely sure what's going on in the background in terms of how much data is actually being retrieved from the server.

```
collectionRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1).once('value').then(snap => {
    if (snap.numChildren() > 0) {
        alert("not empty");
    } else {
        alert("empty!");
    }
});
```

The key difference between this code and the snippet you originally tried is using the `value` listener instead of the `child_added` listener. The `value` listener will return whatever value is there, and more importantly returns `null` if there's nothing (reference doesn't exist). The `child_added` listener runs once per children, so if there are no children, it never runs.

Comment: I'm not sure how the approach with rules would work, but your other approach sounds good.

Comment: Added a clarification between the `value` and `child_added` listeners that explains why @FrankvanPufelen's original code didn't work.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that you can't have an empty array in Firebase for sec

Comment: @Callam I forgot that too. At first I thought, that your second approach is what I described as 1. in the question and `.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1)` are excessive since you're fetching whole value anyways. It turns out, that it actually limits the number of children `snap` will have: `snap.numChildren()` will return `0` or `1`, nothing else. Further, if you do `snap.child()` with a key of an existing child, but not the first child, `exists()` and `val()` will yield `false` and `null` respectively. Neat! This leads me to belief, that it's actually efficient.
Can some Firebaser confirm that?

Answer (score 1):

Don't quote me on this, but I remember reading somewhere that directly accessing a node is pretty efficient already (even if there are large numbers of children).

That being said, perhaps your best solution is to add a counter for the number of children and directly read that value.